# Retirar dados de uma tabela a partir de média de notas de outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
Tabela - lista
id |  nota
1  |  10
2  |  8
3  |  7
1  |  8
3  |  9
```

Eu quero que seja feita a média das notas daqueles que têm o mesmo ID, e para isso criei a seguinte query:

```
SELECT AVG(nota) FROM lista GROUP BY id
```

Com esta query queria ainda retirar toda a informação de outra tabela a partir dos id dependendo da média que tenham, por exemplo se a média de um id for superior a 9 são listados os nomes desses ids que estão em outra tabela.

```
Tabela - informacao
id   |  nome
1    |  Teste1
2    |  Teste2
3    |  Teste3
4    |  Teste4
```

Pela minha pesquisa é necessário existir uma query dentro de outra só que irá resultar sempre em erro pois não é possível comparar a média de diversos resultados com um numero. Lembrando que quero utilizar isto para listar os nomes da outra tabela caso estes tenham uma média de nota superior. Está um pequeno exemplo do que eu quero fazer (o exemplo a baixo está errado):

```
select informacao.* from informacao, lista where informacao.id like lista.id 
and 9<(SELECT AVG(nota) FROM lista GROUP BY id)
```

No final da query queria conseguir ter o nome de todos os que tivessem a média de notas superior a um valor escolhido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select 
*,
(select avg(nota)  from lista where lista.id =informacao.id) as media
 from informacao

Comment: Hora que chegar no meu computador, dou uma melhorada na resposta

Comment: Obrigado :) já consegui encontrar uma solução graças a você. Ficou assim:
Select * from informacao where 7 <= (select avg(nota) from lista where lista.id=informacao.id)